# SAP DBTech JDBC : Feature not supported : Scalar UDF does not support SQL Statement

Tags: sql-server, hana, hana-studio

I'm new at HANA Studio, so please excuse me.

I am getting an error while creating function in SAP HANA Studio. Here's my function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION "PAYROLLDBTEST".GetAbsenteeismDays
(
-- Add the parameters for the function here
EmpID integer,
StartDate Datetime,
EndDate Datetime
)
RETURNS AbsDays float
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT   
SQL SECURITY INVOKER 
AS
AbsDays float;
BEGIN

 (SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, "fromDate", "toDate") + 1) AS AbsentDays into AbsDays
                FROM HEM1
WHERE "empID" = :EmpID AND "fromDate" BETWEEN :StartDate AND :EndDate
                 AND "toDate" BETWEEN :StartDate AND :EndDate
                 );
RETURNS AbsDays;
```

> error :
>
> "Could not execute 'CREATE FUNCTION "PAYROLLDBTEST".GetAbsenteeismDays
>   ( -- Add the parameters for the function here ...' in 2 ms 807 µs . 
>   SAP DBTech JDBC: [257] (at 576): sql syntax error: incorrect syntax
>   near "RETURNS": line 23 col 1 (at pos 576)  "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of functions in HANA: **Table functions** and **scalar functions**.

According to the SAP HANA SQL Script Reference (SPS 07) using DDL and DML within a **table function** is not allowed. **Scalar functions** do not support any kind of SQL-statements.

You return only a value and not a table, so you are trying to create a **scalar function**. Your mentioned example, executing a Select-statement inside a scalar function, won't work. But instead of creating a function you can also easily create a **procedure** containing the same functionality (if you really only need to get one float number).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "PAYROLLDBTEST"."GetAbsenteeismDays" (
      in EmpID integer,
      in StartDate Datetime,
      in EndDate Datetime,
      out AbsentDays float )
   LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
   SQL SECURITY INVOKER 
   -- DEFAULT SCHEMA <Schema>
   READS SQL DATA AS
BEGIN
   SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, "fromDate", "toDate") + 1) into AbsentDays
      FROM HEM1
      WHERE "empID" = :EmpID
         AND "fromDate" BETWEEN :StartDate AND :EndDate
         AND "toDate" BETWEEN :StartDate AND :EndDate
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The downside of @hoffman's solution is that you can't use a `PROCEDURE` in a projection (like a `WHERE`-part of a query):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE "myProcedure"('param') > 5;
```

gives

```
cannot use procedure or table function in select projection column
```

From HANA 11 on scalar functions *do* support SQL so there is no need to use `PROCEDURE`s here any more (see https://scn.sap.com/thread/3861611)

*happy*